# Again! In Ubuntu 32 bit: Eclipse can't execute appt in Android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, aapt

"Error executing aapt. Please check aapt is present at ... /platform tools/aapt"

I am trying to build Android apps using Eclipse Android SDK in Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu 32bit 10.10 in two different computers and I can't fix the problems now.

I installed Eclipse, ADT plugin, Android SDK, all Android APIs, ...and also I have set Preferences to Android SDK folder. I also carefully put all SDK and Eclipse in my username folder to make sure I fully have right permission.

I also try to use google to find similar cases. Most cases use 64 bit Ubuntu.
I also fix the GNU compiler and some instructions here.

But now I am really hopeless. It looks like this problem is really serious.

I really appreciate all of your helps.
Thanks so much

ddienle@gmail.com
ledangdien@yahoo.com
Thanks again

*Also, I try to restart my Computer many times and try to install many different version
of Eclipse. Each time I set Preferences for Android SDK, the following message box occur
 "Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/sdc/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied"
Now I try everything but they don't work*

Comment: Can you do "ls -ld /home/sdc/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools" to make sure the execute bit is set?

Comment: Can you execute it (adb) from the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the adt-eclipse-bundle?

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

You have some wrong permissions. Perhaps some files are owned by the root user because of using sudo when it wasn't needed. All files in your home directory should be owned by your user. You can fix that with the following:

```
sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER /home/sdc/
```